# "On the shore" or "at the shore"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell please if both *at* and *on* are acceptable when talking about being on the surface of the shore. For example:

> I was standing **on**/**at** the shore when the boat reached the pier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side note: You should say "the boat" or "a boat", not just "boat". But to your question:

Both "on" and "at" are valid here and there's no clear difference in meaning.

If I heard someone say "on the shore" in this context, I'd likely take him to mean that he was standing right by the water line, within a few feet of the water. But "at the shore" could mean somewhat further away. But wow, that would be a nit-picky distinction and I'm not sure that other English speakers would take it the same way.